# Subquery em Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho um código que visa retornar faturas em aberto de um cliente em um período de tempo específico. Porém quero adicionar um campo que apresente o número total de faturas, independente do período do débito.

O código está assim:

```
SELECT
    fatura.num_cli "Cliente", -- Código do cliente
    fatura.num_doc "Número do documento", -- Número da NF
    fatura.dta_venc "Vencimento", -- Data de vencimento
    cliente.cod_situ "Situação" -- Situação do cliente, está em outra tabela
FROM fatura
LEFT OUTER JOIN cliente ON fatura.num_cli = cliente.cod_cliente
WHERE fatura.cod_situ_com = 'AB' -- Situação da fatura - aberto
AND trunc(fatura.dta_venc) between '01-mai-2018' and '31-mai-2018' -- Período de vencimento
```

Porém, além disso, queria adicionar um campo que retornasse a contagem do número de faturas em aberto, independente do vencimento.
A estrutura das tabelas é a seguinte:

---

Fatura:
num_doc | num_cli |  dta_venc  | cod_situ
01 | 12225   |  01-mar-2018 | AB

---

Cliente:
cod_cliente | nom_cli | cpf | cod_situ
1201 | João | 00000000000 | ajuizado

---

No caso, cada cliente pode ter várias faturas, e cada fatura está vinculada a um cliente.

O código deve retornar o Número de cliente; o total de faturas em aberto desse cliente, independente do período (esse seria o sub select); o código da fatura em aberto e o vencimento da fatura (esses dois dentro do período estabelecido).

Comment: Você provavelmente terá que fazer um `sub-select`. Para te ajudarmos mais é necessário que você coloque a estrutura das sua tabelas e se possível até alguns dados para testarmos.
O melhor dos mundos seria você colocar sua estrutura e dados no sqlfiddle.com e nos disponibilizar. Além disso, seria interessante você colocar o resultado esperado da `query`.

Comment: como o@RobertodeCampos falou, teria de fazer uma subquery, caso contrário vai ter de usar group by, e agrupar todos os campos que tem no seu select para fazer numa única query, mas sem ver as estruturas das tabelas, difícil te ajudar

Comment: Editei a pergunta para inserir a estrutura das tabelas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alterei um pouco a sua lógica para chegar no resultado.
Imagino que você pode ter cliente sem faturas, então a base do teu SQL é a tabela de `CLIENTE`.

A partir dela fiz um `left join` para trazer as faturas no período e fiz o sub-select para trazer o total de faturas.

O filtro para as faturas deve ficar junto com o `left join`, pois senão se você colocar no where, o `left join` vira `inner join`.

```
select
  b.NOM_CLI,
  a.NUM_CLI "Cliente",   
  a.NUM_DOC "Número do documento",
  a.DTA_VENC "Vencimento",
  b.COD_SITU "Situação",
  (select count(*) from FATURA c where c.NUM_CLI = b.COD_CLIENTE) TotalFatura
from
  CLIENTE b
  left join FATURA a on 
     b.COD_CLIENTE = a.NUM_CLI 
     and a.COD_SITU = 'AB' 
     and a.DTA_VENC between TO_DATE('01/01/2018', 'dd/MM/yyyy') and TO_DATE('31/12/2018', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

#### Exemplo prático

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a54d70/15